# How to trigger a event for the Mail service?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

How to trigger a event for the Mail service?

*Example*

If mail template code equals **mail.order.complete** add bcc?

Comment: it is pretty well explained at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail you should create a Mailable class where you choose your to's, body... and then trigger it creating a new instance of this class like Mail::send(new YourMailableClass($user));

Comment: @CarlosFdev Thanks just looking too much add the october cms docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OctoberCMS is built on Laravel 5.1 and to do handle mail events you will need handle it within your `Plugin.php` file.
For example to handle the process just before the mails being sent:

```
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    [...]

    public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen('mailer.sending', function(){
        });
    }
}
```

To learn more about events in OctoberCMS and Laravel you can check out these links:
https://octobercms.com/docs/services/events

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail